# Resize markers in Google maps api V3

Tags: javascript, maps

I have an associative array holding the path of the image according to the type.

```
var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {  icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinde/a2/8.gif',   },
  bar: {  icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',   }
};
```

The marker is created in:

```
var icon = customIcons[icones] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,   });
```

But icons appear too big. How can I resize them to (30, 30) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the icons as [marker images](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerImage) like this:

`icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( URL_GOES_HERE , undefined, undefined, undefined, new google.maps.Size(30, 30));`

Comment: i cannot create the images like this because the image path is depended on the "icones" value.

Comment: @redfrogsbinary You should be able to, since, for example, your customIcons[icones].icon contains a string with the url of the icon you want, then it would be `icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( **icon.icon** , undefined, undefined, undefined, new google.maps.Size(30, 30));`

Comment: what about the map and positiion. Where is it defined?

Comment: @redfrogsbinary You would define them as you usually do `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( icon.icon , undefined, undefined, undefined, new google.maps.Size(30, 30)),   });
`